# Integrate Redmine with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, redmine, redmine-plugins

How to integrate Redmine with Jenkins. My basic requirnment is to open ticket in redmine if the jenkins build get failed. I had added the Redmine Plugin from Jenkins and tried to use it. But getting error.

[image: Redmine Integration with jenkins screenshot of actual values used[![Entered API key as required.] ][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHzlT.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHzlT.png)

Below are the checkpoints - 

`1. My Jenkins server can ping to Redmine
2. I have configured Redmine in the jenkins
3. I have Redmine Admin Access
4. Rest Web API is enabled in the Redmine.`

getting below error - 

`Started by user admin
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Redmine_test
[Redmine_test] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins885296173512363301.sh
+ pwd
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Redmine_test
Build step 'Aggregate Redmine ticket metrics' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE`